# Order a SELECT query by a column not specified in the SELECT in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, moodle

I'm using this query in MS SQL Server 2016:

```
select MAX(DATEADD(s, timecreated, '19700101 02:00:00')) AS last_active_on, courseid
from mdl_logstore_standard_log
where eventname = '\core\event\course_viewed'
group by courseid
order by last_active_on desc, courseid;
```

to get a list of the most recently accessed courses in Moodle:

| last_active_on | courseid |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-07 15:00:33.000 | 11450 |
| 2021-12-07 15:00:27.000 | 11365 |
| 2021-12-07 15:00:10.000 | 11363 |
| 2021-12-07 15:00:02.000 | 11068 |
| 2021-12-07 14:59:55.000 | 11430 |
| 2021-12-07 14:59:46.000 | 11171 |
| 2021-12-07 14:59:38.000 | 11413 |
| 2021-12-07 14:58:20.000 | 11362 |
| 2021-12-07 14:58:07.000 | 1 |
| 2021-12-07 14:56:36.000 | 11268 |

However, I only want the ''courseid'' column, like this:

| courseid |
| --- |
| 11450 |
| 11365 |
| 11363 |
| 11068 |
| 11430 |
| 11171 |
| 11413 |
| 11362 |
| 1 |
| 11268 |

How do I exclude the ''last_active_on'' column **while retaining the order that the courseid is returned** when I use the "*order by last_active_on desc, courseid;*"?

<sup>(The timecreated column contains a unix timestamp, so I use dateadd() to format it into a "normal" date.)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the alias in the `ORDER BY` with the expression and remove the expression from the list after `SELECT`.

```
SELECT courseid
       FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log
       WHERE eventname = '\core\event\course_viewed'
       GROUP BY courseid
       ORDER BY max(dateadd(s, timecreated, '19700101 02:00:00')) DESC,
                courseid ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column position

eg:

```
ORDER BY 1
```